# How to plot Scatters with marginal density plots use Python?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to plot a graph that is similar to the picture as shown in (https://i.stack.imgur.com/URtfp.png) using python. Could you please show me how to do that? Thank you very much

Comment: you ever get a solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The seaborn [jointplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.jointplot.html) function provides output similar to this if you use the hue parameter.

```
import seaborn as sns
tips = sns.load_dataset('tips')
g = sns.jointplot(data=tips, x="total_bill", y="tip", hue="smoker")
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.show()
```